# date range picker html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, daterangepicker

I wanted to come out with a date range picker where shows in picture below. [ideal output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hz1yf89bhalnpl7/date.JPG?dl=0)

Here is my updated code that I doing now and the output I have it now.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#fromperiod").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      $("#toperiod").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
  });
  $("#toperiod").datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function(selectedDate) {
      $("#fromperiod").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.picker {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  padding : 4px;
}
input {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Period</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='picker'>
          <label for="fromperiod">From</label>
          <input type="text" id="fromperiod" name="from">
          <label for="toperiod">to</label>
          <input type="text" id="toperiod" name="to">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my output based on the code. [output](https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=edit%20date.JPG)

Comment: well its going to need some CSS styling to look like the output you want, have you tried anything?

Comment: @zedd i have try to do some changes in html code. but still the same. Can you provide some guide on the css styling part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was recently tasked with implementing a date range picker similar to the one in Google Analytics. After a bit of searching around I found [this JQueryUI widget](http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/) that works very well, and can be styled easily using [JQueryUI's ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

Unless you're learning or practising, then using existing code, assets and libraries is almost always the best option. The phrases "Don't reinvent the wheel" and "Standing on the shoulders of giants" tend to get tossed around in classrooms and lecture halls for this very reason!

Comment: i have try it previously. but it seem like having conflict with another date input.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the below example, I modified your code ..

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
.wrapper{
    display : inline;
    border:1px solid lightgray;
    padding:4px;
    box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}
input {
    border:0;
}
label {
color : gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
Period :  
<div class='wrapper'>
    <label for="from">from:</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from">
    <label for="to">to:</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to">
</div>
```

Comment: i have update my code . can you look at it see what is the problem.

Comment: Fix the styles 
   `.picker {
      display: inline;
      border: 1px solid lightgray;
      padding : 4px;
    }
    input {
      border: 0;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example on how you can style it, its creates a wrapping `#picker` element that gets the shadow and border, then removes the childrens borders, and puts them in-line.

http://jsfiddle.net/truxwruj/

```
.picker > * {
    display:inline;
    border:0;
}
.picker {
    border:1px solid lightgray;
    padding:4px;
    box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}
```

Comment: i have update my code and output. can you look at it and see what is the problem. thanks

Comment: @susu well, i have updated my answer to use a class instead of ID as in your changed code. This gives a nice result if you just use it

Comment: it work and output is what i want to get it. thanks :D